# Python script won't run because of TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I came across [this website](http://www.automatingosint.com/blog/2016/12/vacuuming-image-metadata-from-the-wayback-machine/) and tried to test-run [the code presented there](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automatingosint/osint_public/master/waybackexif/waybackimages.py) so I could adjust it later.

Upon realising it was written in Python2, I converted it into Python 3 manually. I fixed "print" and "urlparse" statements and removed

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")"
```

(Google said it was unnecessary in Python3. Really?).

When I now run the code, I get the following output and I have no idea what to do to fix this since I am very new to Python. I looked at similar questions but the solutions there couldn't fix this code.

```
[*] Retrieved 89 possible stored URLs
[*] Retrieving https://web.archive.org/web/20110823161411/http://www.oct282011.com/ (1 of 89)
[*] Retrieving https://web.archive.org/web/20110830211214/http://www.oct282011.com/ (2 of 89)
[+] Adding new image: https://web.archive.org/web/20110830211214im_/http://www.oct282011.com/st.jpg
[+] Adding new image: https://web.archive.org/web/20110830211214im_/http://www.oct282011.com/itswhatyouknow_itsnotamystery_mostofyouhavefoundit.png
[+] Adding new image: https://web.archive.org/web/20110830211214im_/http://www.oct282011.com/sngl.jpg
[+] Adding new image: https://web.archive.org/web/20110830211214im_/http://www.oct282011.com/qst.png
[*] Retrieving https://web.archive.org/web/20110831172158/http://www.oct282011.com/ (3 of 89)
[+] Adding new image: https://web.archive.org/web/20110831172158im_/http://www.oct282011.com/0light.png
[+] Adding new image: https://web.archive.org/web/20110831172158im_/http://www.oct282011.com/itswhatyouknow_itsnotamystery_mostofyouhavefoundit.png
[+] Adding new image: https://web.archive.org/web/20110831172158im_/http://www.oct282011.com/sngl.jpg
[+] Adding new image: https://web.archive.org/web/20110831172158im_/http://www.oct282011.com/0.png
[*] Retrieving https://web.archive.org/web/20110903151702/http://www.oct282011.com/ (4 of 89)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7152635ed042> in <module>
    123 print("[*] Retrieved %d possible stored URLs" % len(results.assets))
    124 
--> 125 image_paths = get_image_paths(results)
    126 
    127 print("[*] Retrieved %d image paths." % len(image_paths))

<ipython-input-3-7152635ed042> in get_image_paths(packed_results)
     54 
     55         # parse out all image tags
---> 56         soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result)
     57         image_list = soup.findAll("img")
     58 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, parse_only, from_encoding, exclude_encodings, **kwargs)
    265         if hasattr(markup, 'read'):        # It's a file-type object.
    266             markup = markup.read()
--> 267         elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
    268                 (isinstance(markup, bytes) and not b'<' in markup)
    269                 or (isinstance(markup, str) and not '<' in markup)

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

My questions are:

1. Why does Python point at three code lines (126,56,267) and why in this strange order? Are there
   three errors or is only the lowest-numbered line (56) of importance here?
2. What is the problem and how can it be fixed? Please keep in
   mind I
   am    a total beginner.

I don't know if this is important but am using Python3 in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions at once. The 1. code lines in strange order are a "Traceback" as the heading says – this word should allow searching for explanations. As for the 2. problem, please see the [mcve] and [help] pages how to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [`result = asset.fetch()` call returns `None`](https://github.com/automatingosint/osint_public/blob/e8f4c1c3fbc7b60967e2f07cd790a4fad9d54c4b/waybackexif/waybackimages.py#L55-L56) and that breaks things down the line.

You could add something like

```
if not result:
    print('Result was None:', asset)
    continue
```

after that line to skip the assets which couldn't get fetched.

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

So actually the three lines is a path to identify the *real error*: The first line is the function which was called that failed, but it throws an error because of another function in that first function, which is the second line/arrow. The second line/function throws an error due to an error in the second function, which is the third and final line. An example would be

```py
def f1(a):
    b = f2(a)
   

def f2(a):
   c = 1/a
```

if you call `f1(0)` you'll get the error

```py
f1(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\test.py in <module>
----> 1 f1(0)

c:\Users\test.py in f1(a)
      1 def f1(a):
----> 2     b = f2(a)

c:\Users\test.py in f2(a)
      1 def f2(a):
----> 2    c = 1/a

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

which says "there is an error in the call `f1(0)`" (first line/arrow) "but that is due to the call `b=f2(a)`" (second line/arrow) "which fails on the line `c=1/a`" (third line/arrow).

That way you can back-trace your error. If it just said "there is an error in `f1(0)`" it would be very difficult to trace what the *real* error is (`c=1/0`)

**2)**
It might be due to `results` being empty i.e does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to other answers:

I believe the first part of your question has been answered but as to the second part, in line 267 you could specify:

```
elif markup and len(markup) >= 256 and ((isinstance(markup, bytes) and not b'<' in markup) or (isinstance(markup, str) and not '<' in markup))
```